# Discord JDA + JavaFX TextArea bug

Tags: java, discord

My goal is to add a GUI to my bot using `JavaFX`.

I have added a `TextArea` and named it Logs. 
Here is my code:

```
<code>
@FXML private TextArea Logs;


@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        Logs = new TextArea();

}

    @Override 
    public void onMessageReceived(MessageReceivedEvent event) {
        String Prefix = event.getGuild().getName() + " > " +event.getAuthor().getName() + " : ";
        String Content = event.getMessage().getContent();
        String Message = Prefix + System.lineSeparator() + Content;

        System.out.println(Message);
        Logs.setText(Message);
    }
</code>
```

The thing is, 
 `system.out.println(Message)` works, but I just get a `NullPointerException` for the `Logs.setText` part.

Comment: Sorry to bump this but still having issues. 
I cant seem to make this work at all.